# How to fix jQuery conflict?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, jquery-events

I used more than three JavaScripts in Magento and I tried to fix some of the scripts (conflict I think) and it works but the last jQuery (jcarousel)  it can be swapped to another category if I click the tabs "new arrival" and "most popular" but now it doesn't work, but if I comment out accordion js file it works but accordion can't work.. :(

Click here : http://thaiamuletstore.com/main1/index.php

head.phtml

---

```
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>


<link href="http://thaiamuletstore.com/main1/style/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://thaiamuletstore.com/main1/style/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://thaiamuletstore.com/main1/style/tango/skin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thaiamuletstore.com/main1/js/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thaiamuletstore.com/main1/js/Untlitie.js"></script>                           <!-- this-control-jcarousel-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thaiamuletstore.com/main1/js/470fe3190c7d0ea4aacc14677c226000.js"></script>   <!--this-control-Accordion-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thaiamuletstore.com/main1/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>               <!-- this-control-jcarousel-->




<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://thaiamuletstore.com/main1/style/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<![endif]-->





<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thaiamuletstore.com/main1/js/hoverIntent.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thaiamuletstore.com/main1/js/superfish.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thaiamuletstore.com/main1/js/organictabs.jquery.js"></script>

<script src=http://thaiamuletstore.com/main1/js/menu_effect/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

This is the thing for your rescue.

Comment: yeah..i try with put in th head <script type="text/javascript" src="http://thaiamuletstore.com/main1/js/mw_js/jquery_noconflict.js"></script> but some script start to work but now i just conflict with accordion tab..

Comment: You need to check if you are not trying to invoke JS functions on different DOM elements with the same IDS or not...

Comment: but some browser work perfectly but some browser not..why this happen? you can see the different  from mozilla and ie7